# Update Multiple rows with all diffrent values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014, multiple-columns

I have a spread sheet with all the User ID's and their updated address's, I have over 10K user accounts that I need to update with their new addresses, I cant write a script for all the 10K Users, how would I go about this?

If I were to use `Update Users Set Address=('','') where UserId In ()`
This gives me Error's. With no info just saying syntax Error new address.

I have few UserID's and Values I could showcase, for example: 
I have UserID's `(1,2,3)` and the Address is `(1 Street,2 Street, 3 Street)`

How can I run one script to update all 3 Records at once? 
I expect the output updating all 3 files with the updated address. 
Thanks for all your Help in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the data into a table into the database and then use `update` with a `join`:

```
update o
    set address = n.address
    from originaltable o join
         newaddresses n
         on o.userid = n.userid;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, thanks for the quick reply, if you don't mind could you give me an example of loading the data into the table?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017